# Get Real Time Date From a Site(ex. Weather Prediction ) With Python

Tags: python, websocket, python-requests

We have a Site that values are change every 20 millisecond for example
Weather Prediction sites. and I want to get real data and save them on redis in real time with python.

If I Use Request Library in python actually my program should be send a https request to server and get response that action may delay much more than 100 millisecond and I Can't get Real Time changes value.

So I don't Know Which Library is Useful for me?

Comment: The question is meaningless. If you want to connect to a stock exchange, they'll tell you how to do it. Stock Exchanges don't just put real-time data on their sites. They charge a *ton of money for that privilege*, use specialized formats like FIX to do so and require extensive testing before they allow anyone to connect to their systems. Because bad coding puts load on *their* servers and delays *their* and others' transaction processing

Comment: In fact, if you don't already know how to do it, you won't be allowed to even talk to them. You may be able to get access (with a time delay) from another provider, which, again, is going to charge lots of money,  tell you how to connect and secure the connection and guide you through the testing and certification process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For extracting data from a website without sending HTTP Requests to the Server to reload the whole webpage is to use Selenium Web driver instead.

Typically, on the web there are 2 types of websites:

1. Static Websites - the ones that show the webpage fetched from the backend, and don't update on the frontend
2. Dynamic Websites - the ones that are developed using a Front-end like React/Angular/Vue and fetch updates from the backend using API, without reloading the whole webpage.

To scrape a Static Website, its recommended to use the Requests Package, since it sends a HTTP/HTTPS Request to reload the whole webpage. Since in your case, the webpage is dynamic, you should work with Selenium. In the Selenium Code, you should first pass the website to be targeted, and then you can write a loop, which triggers a function to fetch the contents after every few milliseconds.
Tip: Use Selenium with headless to prevent the browser window from opening.

PS: Scraping is not legal with a lot of websites, since you are accessing their content programmatically. These websites have their own API's which are paid to provide you with the required content. So scrape at your own risk.